# Sharing typescript code between backend, react and react-native clients

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I've started to convert my project to typescript and in a meanwhile I decided to improve code reuse between node.js backend, react web client and react-native mobile client.

Here is my project structure:

```
 ├ commons (code shared between backend and frontend, mostly type definitions and utils
 ├ clients (code shared between web and mobile clients, depends on commons: containers, utils, forms... )
 ├ backend (express server, depends on commons)
 ├ web (create-react-app, not ejected, no SSR needed, depends on clients)
 ├ mobile (react-native client, depends on clients)
```

What I've tried so far:

- Symlinks. Could't make them work with react-native (see [metro bundler issue](https://github.com/facebook/metro-bundler/issues/1)).
  This can probably be solved by using haul, but adds extra complexity by making haul work with typescript. Also, haul doesn't seem to work with Mobile Center, which I use for publishing mobile apps
- Using `rootDirs` or `paths` in tsconfig.json. Typescript compiler doesn't merge/bundle outputs, so this means I need to support 3 different solutions to merge generated code. Also doesn't work well with my IDE.
- Using [WML](https://github.com/wix/wml). I tried two approaches:

  - Linking `commons` and `clients` to packages inside `node_modules` of web/mobile/server. To do this, I have to generate declarations, which is burdening because it requires exposing all imports (see [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9944)). Also doesn't play well with yarn, which will remove linked package every time it installs something new.
  - Linking `commons` and `clients` to separate source folder inside source folders of web, mobile and backend. This is what I use in current JS version of my project. It works, but it has some downsides:

    - Long relative imports (probably can be solved by supporting 3 different solutions for module aliases)
    - wml sometimes breaks in backround, which leads to some confusing albeit easy to discover errors
    - doesn't work well with hot reloading

I'm looking for a solution which is not too complex (requires minimal configuration on web/mobile/backend sides) and plays well with Webstorm.
It probably doesn't exist now, so I'd like to hear what other solutions people here use for similar project setups.

Answer (score 2):

In the similar situation to yours I did the following:

1. `commons` gets published as a separate [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/). You can make it private if necessary.
2. `clients` depends on `commons` package and gets published to npm as well. Again - private if required.
3. `web` and `mobile` projects both reuse npm packages created above.

Comment: So you have to publish `commons` and `clients` every time you change something inside those packages, and then you have to update dependencies in `web` and `mobile` and `backend`? If done manually, this is annoying, especially now when I'm migrating and change things often. Also, this approach is too affected by issue with declarations. However I think this is sane approach if shared code doesn't change very often.

Comment: You are correct. In my case when projects have stabilized - changes does not happen too often and therefore it is not an issue. And of course as you have said - if its troublesome you can always make a script to run those operations at once.